# Iterating through a list of Pandas DF's to then iterate through each DF's row

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

This may be a slightly insane question...
I've got a single Pandas DF of articles which I have then split into multiple DF's so each DF only contains the articles from a particular year. I have then put these variables into a list called `box_of_years`.

```
indexed_df = article_db.set_index('date')
indexed_df = indexed_df.sort_index()

year_2004 = indexed_df.truncate(before='2004-01-01', after='2004-12-31')
year_2005 = indexed_df.truncate(before='2005-01-01', after='2005-12-31')
year_2006 = indexed_df.truncate(before='2006-01-01', after='2006-12-31')
year_2007 = indexed_df.truncate(before='2007-01-01', after='2007-12-31')
year_2008 = indexed_df.truncate(before='2008-01-01', after='2008-12-31')
year_2009 = indexed_df.truncate(before='2009-01-01', after='2009-12-31')
year_2010 = indexed_df.truncate(before='2010-01-01', after='2010-12-31')
year_2011 = indexed_df.truncate(before='2011-01-01', after='2011-12-31')
year_2012 = indexed_df.truncate(before='2012-01-01', after='2012-12-31')
year_2013 = indexed_df.truncate(before='2013-01-01', after='2013-12-31')
year_2014 = indexed_df.truncate(before='2014-01-01', after='2014-12-31')
year_2015 = indexed_df.truncate(before='2015-01-01', after='2015-12-31')
year_2016 = indexed_df.truncate(before='2016-01-01', after='2016-12-31')

box_of_years = [year_2004, year_2005, year_2006, year_2007,
                year_2008, year_2009, year_2010, year_2011,
                year_2012, year_2013, year_2014, year_2015,
                year_2016]
```

I've written various functions to tokenize, clean up and convert the tokens into a `FreqDist` object and wrapped those up into a single function called `year_prep()`. This works fine when I do

```
year_2006 = year_prep(year_2006)
```

...but is there a way I can iterate across every year variable, apply the function and have it transform the same variable, short of just repeating the above for every year?

I know repeating myself would be the simplest way, but not necessarily the cleanest. I may perhaps have this backwards and do the slicing later on but at that point I feel like the layers of lists will be out of hand as I'm going from a list of years to a list of years, containing a list of articles, containing a list of every word in the article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by [`year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.year.html) with custom function:

```
import pandas as pd

start = pd.to_datetime('2004-02-24')
rng = pd.date_range(start, periods=30, freq='50D')

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': rng, 'a':range(30)})  
#print (df)

def f(x):
    print (x)
    #return year_prep(x)
    #some custom output 
    return x.a + x.Date.dt.month

print (df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.year).apply(f))
```

Comment: So I used this
`def f(x): 
     print(x)`
`grouped = df.groupby(df['date'].dt.year)`
`grouped['clean_text'].apply(f)` and it worked, printing out the contents of the 'clean_text' column in a grouped list so it looks good in theory. Now I just have to work out how you call upon specific groups, for example if I wanted to plot the result of frequency counts just for the year 2008.

Comment: so basically now I have my grouped database, how do I point at just group 2008?

Comment: Then use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) - try `df[df.Date.dt.year == 2008]`

Comment: `AttributeError: Cannot access attribute 'dt' of 'SeriesGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method.`

Comment: It looks like you need `reset_index` - `print (df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.year).apply(f).reset_index())`

Comment: Or maybe rename column also `print (df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.year).apply(f).reset_index(name='col'))`

Comment: `AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'groupby' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method`

Comment: Hmmm, do you assign output? `df1= (df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.year).apply(f).reset_index(name='col'))` and then `df2 = df1[df1.Date.dt.year == 2008]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120808/discussion-between-james-allen-robertson-and-jezrael).